# How to create index for nearly infinite dataset

Tags: algorithm, optimization, memory

I've discovered [this website](https://babelia.libraryofbabel.info/slideshow.html) that adapt the idea of the babel library but with images.

The canvas here is of 640x416 pixels, each one being an RGB color and can represent any combination possible pixels possible for an image. Considering the sheer amount of space required for storing all the images, I'm highly doubting the all the images are present on the webserver (it would represent around 3168.75 petabytes), so I'm assuming that the images are generated when accessing the page.

So here is my question, how is it possible to have such a dataset and still give it ID's that only look like few numbers long (like 5224060665946282) ?

Since the IDs must represent uniquely the image, and it's impossible to store all the images, it means that the image can be regenerated exactly from the IDs, but all my attempts at doing something similar just end up in encoding each RGB pixel of the image as binary and compress it to use this as a number. This is still hundreds of thousands numbers long for each IDs.

Comment: Could you just store the random seed?

Comment: "Image locations are typically almost 1,000,000 digits long, which makes them somewhat unwieldy. To copy an image's full location, click on the truncated image location beneath it (the number prefaced by "babelia #" in the example at right)."

Comment: @Ripi2 what you have here isn't the size of each image combined it the number of images. (16M color possible for each pixels on a 640x416 grid)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for Python 3 assuming that you have installed `pycryptodome` and `Pillow`.

The idea is to turn the number into a string of bytes with content at the start. Then use encryption to turn that into a mess. You need content at the start because we're using block based encryption, so there needed to be content in the very first block to get anything interesting out.

And then turn the bytes into an Image.

See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html for more on the object that you get back.

```
from PIL import Image
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def integer_to_gif (gif_id, height=640, width=416):
    # Create a boring byte array of the right size with content at the start.
    orig_bytes = gif_id.to_bytes(height*width*3, 'little') #height*width*3, 'little')

    # Use encryption to create a seemingly random byte array of the right size.
    key = b'siXteeN ByTe kEy'
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    display_bytes = cipher.encrypt(orig_bytes)

    # Turn bytes into image
    return Image.frombytes("RGB", (height, width), display_bytes)

integer_to_gif(257)
```